# JavaFx Get text from selected CheckBox

Tags: javafx, checkbox

I was trying to get the text from selected CheckBox by clicking the button. My CheckBoxes are being created as children of a vbox and i can not figure out how to make an if statement in onRandom function which collects text of a selected CheckBoxes.

```
package sample;


import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;


public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Button add;
    @FXML
    private Button delete;
    @FXML
    private VBox vbox;
    @FXML
    private TextField text;
    @FXML
    private Button random;
    @FXML
    private ListView listview1;
    @FXML
    private ListView listview2;



    @FXML
    void initialize() {

    }

    @FXML
    public void onAdd(ActionEvent e) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(text.getText());
        vbox.getChildren().add(cb);
        if (text.getText().matches("")) {
            vbox.getChildren().remove(cb);
        }
    }
    @FXML
    public void onDelete(ActionEvent e) {
        vbox.getChildren().removeIf(child -> ((CheckBox) child).isSelected());
    }

    @FXML
    public void onRandom(ActionEvent e) {


    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "collects text of a selected CheckBoxes"?

Comment: The main puropse of onRandom  is to randomize selected CheckBoxes (it's texts) into 2 different ListViews. (When button is pressed selected CheckBoxes randomizes into this ListViews)

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: I got no idea what you want to do

Comment: Ok, so lets say that i want to make an if statement in onRandom (onRandom is a button) where when i check a CheckBox it prints out its text i have given in the TextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modified `onRandom()` method should look like this,

```
@FXML
public void onRandom(ActionEvent e) {
    vbox.getChildren()
        .stream()
        .map(item -> (CheckBox) item)
        .filter(item -> item.isSelected())
        .map(item -> item.getText())
        .filter(text -> Objects.nonNull(text))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

If you need to do some further work other than just printing it out,

```
//replace it with .forEach(System.out::println);
.forEach(text -> {
   // TODO: logics
});
```